# Entity Framework only allow one query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am making a call to the SQL database via Entity Framework, this call takes about 2 mins to execute. 
I want to make sure this call only occurs once. Once the call is made, I place the results in cache. I notice if multiple users are on the site, it can be more than 2 mins till the data is returned, whats the best way to approach this? Should I use a mutex? or does Entity Framework (version 4) have any functionality built in to handle this type of situation. I am using MVC 4. Thank you!

```
public IEnumerable<AdListing> AllActiveAds()
{
    try
    {
    if (PullCache(Constants.CacheKeys.AllActiveAds) == null)
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            db.CommandTimeout = 300;

            List<AdListing> results =
                (from a in
                     db.AdListings
                       .Include("AdPhotos")
                       .Include("tbLocation")
                 where !a.Deleted
                 select a).ToList();

            PushCache(results, Constants.CacheKeys.AllActiveAds);
        }
    }
    return (List<AdListing>) PullCache(Constants.CacheKeys.AllActiveAds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you dont want to make the Website Single access, each process will be talking to the Database. So you would be competing with the Database's own cache if you built a Process wide cache and communicated with it. if the post processing of loaded data is slow enough that can make sense, but that is a slippery slope. Where is the bulk of time spent?.  How many entries are returned.  Is the an SQL trace .  Have you considered a different approach with than all listings and all photos at once ?

Comment: Actually, I am considering to make a db call and not use ALL the photos. A listing can have more than one photo, in most cases I only need to display one photo as the primary photo and not return all photos till the user clicks on the detail view. Any idea on how to accomplish this using the syntax above?

Comment: I would look to use OrderBy, take skip Iqueryable features to get the list and the Main photo 1 page at a time. Why read way beyond the page? I dont even keep the DBContext between calls. If you are planning to cache that you may be info for a slow death website. Read on demand.  I would also suggest you consider using ajax to get the photos

Comment: Why is the query so slow? Either you want to query a very large amout of data or there is a problem with the database backend. Try to optimise it. Try to make a custom database view that queries the same data, but faster. Experiment with it. Put up indexes. You can query millions of records in 2 minutes.